# Add a custom icon zoom level

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, icons, zooming

In Ubuntu's 14.04 file explorer in "Edit > Preferences" it is possible to change icon size under "Icon View Defaults". Zoom level options are: 33%, 50%, 66%, 100%, 150%, 200%, 400%.

Is there any way to add a custom zoom level? For example 80%?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Whats your `nautilus --version` ?

Comment: GNOME nautilus 3.10.1